# React Axios call in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, rest, axios

I am trying to build a 'DataLoader' component that calls a Django Rest API via Axios and for testing purposes shows the results of the API call in an unordered list. The query terms are being generated in a parent component and passed via props.

Initially, the API is called with the query terms manufacturer & model_name both being blank. This part works, after the initial render I can see a unordered list that shows all the expected results.

When the parent component passes new query terms via props to the 'DataLoader' component, the render() function is being executed, as I can see the

```js
<ul><li>Data {this.props.selectedManufacturer}</li><li>Data {this.props.selectedModels}</li></ul>
```

part being executed and re-rendered correctly.

However, it seems that the componentDidMount() function with the Axios part is not being called again. How do I get React to call Axios again once new props have been passed from the parent component to the 'DataLoader' component?

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getDefaultNormalizer } from '@testing-library/react';

class DataLoader extends React.Component {
    state = {
        cars: []
    }
    componentDidMount(props) {
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/firstdraft/api/data?manufacturer=${this.props.selectedManufacturer}&model_name=${this.props.selectedModels}`)
      .then(res => {
        const cars = res.data;
        this.setState({ cars });
        console.log(this.state.cars)
        }
      )
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <h1>Top Selling Cars</h1>
                <ul>{this.state.cars.map(car => <li> {car.model_name}</li>)}</ul>
                <ul><li>Data {this.props.selectedManufacturer}</li><li>Data {this.props.selectedModels}</li></ul>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default DataLoader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical use-case for `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method.

Citing [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

> `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`
>
> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

So, in your case:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const shouldUpdateCars= 
    prevProps.selectedManufacturer !== this.props.selectedManufacturer
    || prevProps.selectedModels!== this.props.selectedModels

  if (shouldUpdateCars) {
    // fetch API and update state
  }
}
```

A full example would be:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getDefaultNormalizer } from '@testing-library/react';

class DataLoader extends React.Component {
    state = {
        cars: []
    }

    fetchCars(manufacturer, models) {
         axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/firstdraft/api/data?manufacturer=${manufacturer}&model_name=${models}`)
      .then(res => {
        const cars = res.data;
        this.setState({ cars });
        console.log(this.state.cars)
        }
      )
    }

    componentDidUpdate(props) {
      const shouldUpdateCarsData = 
        prevProps.selectedManufacturer !== this.props.selectedManufacturer
        || prevProps.selectedModels!== this.props.selectedModels

      if (shouldUpdateCarsData ) {
        // fetch API and update state
        fetchCars(this.props.selectedManufacturer, this.props.selectedModels)
      }
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <h1>Top Selling Cars</h1>
                <ul>{this.state.cars.map(car => <li> {car.model_name}</li>)}</ul>
                <ul><li>Data {this.props.selectedManufacturer}</li><li>Data {this.props.selectedModels}</li></ul>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default DataLoader;
```

Answer (score 0):

use componentDidUpdate and check if prevProps compared to current Props changed then run your axios call.

```js
componentDidUpdatd(prevProps){
  if(prevProps.selectedManufacturer!==this.props.selectedManufacturer){
  //api call here
  }
}
```